# Cannot delete jar from lib/ext folder

Tags: java, jar, jre

I've added a jar in the extension folder of my JRE (`lib/ext`) in order to provide an extension code to my applications. 
Now I want to delete this jar, but I cannot. The error message says:

```
Cannot delete. It is being used by another person or program
```

BTW. My Java program is not running at the same time I want to delete the jar.

How can I remove this jar from the `ext` directory of the JRE?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: I am using windows xp sp2 in a virtual machine.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an obscure process running? If you're using Windows, what does the `processes` window say (Ctrl+Shift+Esc and then the processes tab)?

Comment: well there are a lot of processes running, i cannot even say which one is locking the jar file...

Comment: If nothing else helps, reboot the system than you can be sure that there is no process having a lock in the file.

Comment: Even if I restart i cannot delete the file... :/

Comment: Use the software "Unlocker" for deleting such files. You can download it from here http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/

Comment: Is the folder on a network share or VM shared folder?  Are there automated processes to index the file which might lock it?  Have you tried logging in as another  user on the VM to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Extended ProcessMonitor by Microsoft - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645 is really great tool that could show you which process is using your particular file.

Btw: simplest way - rename your file to some other temporary name (it is possible under windows when file is already blocked by some other program), reboot computer, remove file with your 'temporary file name'.